# Nginx: rewrite http status message in the header (not body)

Tags: nginx

In Nginx, I want to customize the status code message right after the status code:

such as this is the default:

HTTP/1.1 429

and I want to do this:
HTTP/1.1 429 Too many requests

How can I get it done please? Note this is the header not the body at all.